# [terraform][helm-provider][resource] give me context deadline exceeded when tls is enabled

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

I'm geeting a `helm_release.istio_init: context deadline exceeded` when trying to install istio-init to my kubernetes cluster

I'm using helm provider version 0.9.1 with tls enabled...

```
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                    = "${var.cluster["endpoint"]}"
    client_certificate      = "${base64decode(var.cluster["client_certificate"])}"
    client_key              = "${base64decode(var.cluster["client_key"])}"
    cluster_ca_certificate  = "${base64decode(var.cluster["cluster_ca_certificate"])}"
  }
  install_tiller  = "false"
  tiller_image    = "gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.13.1"
  service_account = "${kubernetes_service_account.terraform-tiller.metadata.0.name}"
  namespace       = "${kubernetes_service_account.terraform-tiller.metadata.0.namespace}"
  enable_tls      = "true"
  insecure        = "false"
  client_key = "${file("${data.external.generate_certs.result["terraform_key"]}")}"
  client_certificate = "${file("${data.external.generate_certs.result["terraform_cert"]}")}"
  ca_certificate = "${file("${data.external.generate_certs.result["cert"]}")}"
}

# Installing istio
# Installing istio repository

# defining istio system namespace
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "istio_system" {
  metadata {
    name = "istio-system"
  }
}

data "helm_repository" "istio" {
  name = "istio"
  url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/istio-release/releases/1.1.3/charts/"
}

# Installing istio-init resource
resource "helm_release" "istio_init" {
  depends_on = ["data.external.install_tiller"]
  namespace = "istio-system"
  repository = "${data.helm_repository.istio.metadata.0.name}"
  name       = "istio-init"
  chart = "istio-init"
}
```

I tried with `insecure` flag in `true` and works, but is not the idea.

My expected result is istio-init was installed but I'm got `context deadline exceeded`

This is the terraform plan output

```
terraform plan -out planning/plan.out
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

data.helm_repository.istio: Refreshing state...

------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  + helm_release.istio_init
      id:               <computed>
      chart:            "istio-init"
      disable_webhooks: "false"
      force_update:     "false"
      metadata.#:       <computed>
      name:             "istio-init"
      namespace:        "istio-system"
      recreate_pods:    "false"
      repository:       "istio"
      reuse:            "false"
      reuse_values:     "false"
      status:           "DEPLOYED"
      timeout:          "300"
      verify:           "false"
      version:          "1.1.3"
      wait:             "true"


Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

------------------------------------------------------------------------

This plan was saved to: planning/plan.out

To perform exactly these actions, run the following command to apply:
    terraform apply "planning/plan.out"
```

This the apply command output

```
$ TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform apply "planning/plan.out"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [INFO] Terraform version: 0.11.13
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [INFO] Go runtime version: go1.12
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [INFO] CLI args: []string{"/usr/local/Cellar/terraform/0.11.13/bin/terraform", "apply", "planning/plan.out"}
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: /Users/felipe/.terraformrc
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] File doesn't exist, but doesn't need to. Ignoring.
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [INFO] CLI command args: []string{"apply", "planning/plan.out"}
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [INFO] command: initializing local backend from plan (not set)
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "."
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "/usr/local/Cellar/terraform/0.11.13/bin"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] checking for provider in ".terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-kubernetes_v1.6.2_x4"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "helm", "0.9.1", "/Users/felipe/workspace/terraform-spec/helm/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "kubernetes", "1.6.2", "/Users/felipe/workspace/terraform-spec/helm/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-kubernetes_v1.6.2_x4"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "."
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/usr/local/Cellar/terraform/0.11.13/bin"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in ".terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [INFO] command: backend initialized: *local.Local
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "."
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "/usr/local/Cellar/terraform/0.11.13/bin"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] checking for provider in ".terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] found provider "terraform-provider-kubernetes_v1.6.2_x4"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "helm", "0.9.1", "/Users/felipe/workspace/terraform-spec/helm/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] found valid plugin: "kubernetes", "1.6.2", "/Users/felipe/workspace/terraform-spec/helm/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-kubernetes_v1.6.2_x4"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "."
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/usr/local/Cellar/terraform/0.11.13/bin"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in ".terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64"
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [INFO] backend/local: starting Apply operation
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [INFO] terraform: building graph: GraphTypeApply
iresNew:false, Sensitive:false, Type:0x0}, "status":*terraform.ResourceAttrDiff{Old:"", New:"DEPLOYED", NewComputed:false, NewRemoved:false, NewExtra:interface {}(nil), RequiresNew:false, Sensitive:false, Type:0x0}, "timeout":*terraform.ResourceAttrDiff{Old:"", New:"300", NewComputed:false, NewRemoved:false, NewExtra:interface {}(nil), RequiresNew:false, Sensitive:false, Type:0x0}, "verify":*terraform.ResourceAttrDiff{Old:"", New:"false", NewComputed:false, NewRemoved:false, NewExtra:interface {}(nil), RequiresNew:false, Sensitive:false, Type:0x0}, "version":*terraform.ResourceAttrDiff{Old:"", New:"1.1.3", NewComputed:false, NewRemoved:false, NewExtra:interface {}(nil), RequiresNew:false, Sensitive:false, Type:0x0}, "wait":*terraform.ResourceAttrDiff{Old:"", New:"true", NewComputed:false, NewRemoved:false, NewExtra:interface {}(nil), RequiresNew:false, Sensitive:false, Type:0x0}}, Destroy:false, DestroyDeposed:false, DestroyTainted:false, Meta:map[string]interface {}(nil)}
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] Resource state not found for "helm_release.istio_init": helm_release.istio_init
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [TRACE] Graph after step *terraform.AttachStateTransformer:

helm_release.istio_init - *terraform.NodeApplyableResource
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] ReferenceTransformer: "helm_release.istio_init" references: []
2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] ReferenceTransformer: "provider.helm" references: []
2019-04-25T10:36:02.359-0400 [DEBUG] plugin: starting plugin: path=/Users/felipe/workspace/terraform-spec/helm/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4 args=[/Users/felipe/workspace/terraform-spec/helm/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4]
2019-04-25T10:36:02.363-0400 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for RPC address: path=/Users/felipe/workspace/terraform-spec/helm/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4
2019-04-25T10:36:02.399-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4: plugin address: timestamp=2019-04-25T10:36:02.398-0400 address=/var/folders/rx/lrb60s6929j3ldg6tlwtcf4m0000gn/T/plugin586870690 network=unix
2019-04-25T10:36:02.405-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4: 2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] TLS settings: 
[OMITED]
2019-04-25T10:36:02.813-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4: 2019/04/25 10:36:02 [DEBUG] Fetched istio/istio-init to /Users/felipe/.helm/cache/archive/istio-init-1.1.3.tgz
2019-04-25T10:36:03.097-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4: 2019/04/25 10:36:03 [DEBUG] Fetched istio/istio-init to /Users/felipe/.helm/cache/archive/istio-init-1.1.3.tgz
2019/04/25 10:36:03 [DEBUG] apply: helm_release.istio_init: executing Apply
helm_release.istio_init: Creating...
  chart:            "" => "istio-init"
  disable_webhooks: "" => "false"
  force_update:     "" => "false"
  metadata.#:       "" => "<computed>"
  name:             "" => "istio-init"
  namespace:        "" => "istio-system"
  recreate_pods:    "" => "false"
  repository:       "" => "istio"
  reuse:            "" => "false"
  reuse_values:     "" => "false"
  status:           "" => "DEPLOYED"
  timeout:          "" => "300"
  verify:           "" => "false"
  version:          "" => "1.1.3"
  wait:             "" => "true"
2019-04-25T10:36:04.632-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4: 2019/04/25 10:36:04 [DEBUG] Created tunnel using local port: '50275'
2019-04-25T10:36:04.632-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4: 2019/04/25 10:36:04 [DEBUG] Found TLS settings: configuring helm client with TLS
2019-04-25T10:36:09.634-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4: 2019/04/25 10:36:09 [DEBUG] could not get release context deadline exceeded
2019/04/25 10:36:09 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost, err: 1 error(s) occurred:

* helm_release.istio_init: context deadline exceeded
2019/04/25 10:36:09 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: 1 error(s) occurred:

* helm_release.istio_init: context deadline exceeded

2019/04/25 10:36:09 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* helm_release.istio_init: 1 error(s) occurred:

* helm_release.istio_init: context deadline exceeded

Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.


2019-04-25T10:36:09.645-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4: 2019/04/25 10:36:09 [ERR] plugin: plugin server: accept unix /var/folders/rx/lrb60s6929j3ldg6tlwtcf4m0000gn/T/plugin586870690: use of closed network connection
2019-04-25T10:36:09.648-0400 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin process exited: path=/Users/felipe/workspace/terraform-spec/helm/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-helm_v0.9.1_x4
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but it's nothing to do with Istio. Just having a helm_provider configured for TLS seems totally broken. Removing the certs (either from ~/.helm or from the provider config) will result in no TLS handshake. When there _IS_ a TLS handshake, I get "context deadline exceeded" every time!

Comment: also see this bug: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-helm/pull/245 there is an open PR about it

Comment: @Rich that works, re install tiller with the same certificates

Comment: please explain what you mean? I should re-install tiller via terraform  _again_ after it completes the first install?

Comment: @Rich, the final solution is, you have to setup a HELM_HOME, and put there the certificates and finally reinstall tiller...

remember to delete the tiller deployment and tiller secrets before installation.

Also you can, specify the helm home value in helm provider on terrafom

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error before and it usually means that I'm not running tiller.
I see you have set

```
install_tiller  = "false"
```

which means you need to run it locally.

I run this:

```
tiller -storage secret
```

Comment: I install tiller locally and reinstall tiller with the same certificates.
that do the work.